# Comparing two nvarchar in a function

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a function I want to check whether passed value is equal to a predefined value (@ValX)

I have wrote following function:

```
ALTER Function IsNotInReview(@Val NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ValX NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @ValX = '
{
"httpCode" : 200,
"message" : "OK",
"result" : {
    "items" : {
    "items" : [ ]
    }
}
}
    '

    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@Val)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@ValX))
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0
    END
    RETURN 0

END
```

When I test call the function, I am always getting false value

```
SELECT dbo.IsNotInReview('
{
"httpCode" : 200,
"message" : "OK",
"result" : {
    "items" : {
    "items" : [ ]
    }
}
}
')--should return true

SELECT dbo.IsNotInReview('test')
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated my SP but still getting the same 'false' return value

```
ALTER Function IsNotInReview(@Val NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ValX NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @ValX = '
{
"httpCode" : 200,
"message" : "OK",
"result" : {
    "items" : {
    "items" : [ ]
    }
}
}
    '

    DECLARE @ReturnVal BIT

    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@Val)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@ValX))
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnVal = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnVal = 0
    END
    RETURN @ReturnVal

END



SELECT dbo.IsNotInReview('{
  "httpCode" : 200,
  "message" : "OK",
  "result" : {
    "items" : {
      "items" : [ ]
    }
  }
}') --Return false which is unexpected
```

Comment: change your if `IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@Val)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@ValX))
  
          RETURN 1
    ELSE
    RETURN 0
    return 1`

Comment: I copied your code in my DB and could see it returns '1' as expected.

Comment: try to remove last RETURN 0 from your function dude ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing identical strings. Look at the indentation. I cannot imagine that this is what your intention is, i.e. comparing not only relevant content but also indentation.

A possible solution is to remove all white spaces, line breaks etc. in the string, while skipping over sections enclosed in double quotes.

Edit: Here is a little function which might be useful for you. It removes white spaces from your string while skipping quoted regions. Please test thoroughly, I only wrote it and testet it a bit (I have to go to work now)

```
create function RemoveWhiteSpaces (@String nvarchar(max)) 
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
 declare @result nvarchar(max), @i int, @n int, @inQuotes bit, 
 declar @c0 nchar(1), @c nchar(1)

  set @i=1
  set @n=len(@string)
  set @result=''
  set @inQuotes=0
  set @c='x'

  while @i <= @n begin
    set @c0=@c
    set @c=substring(@string,@i,1)
    if @c='"' and @c0 != '\'
      set @inQuotes= 1 - @inQuotes

    if @inQuotes = 1 or 
      (@inQuotes = 0 and @c not in (' ',char(13), char(10),char(8))) 
      set @result = @result + @c

    set @i=@i+1
  end
  return @result
end
```